# Buddy Boss Remove Functionality - clogging admin-ajax.php file and slowing site down

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been analyzing why my site has been slow and have found a cause of the issue. I have used GT Metrix to work out that the admin-ajax.php file is the slow file and that in the post tab under the waterfall section it labels this as the offender:

```
action=buddyboss_get_follow&group=followers&followNonce=03715c0cae
```

My site is a marketplace and people can add friends but there is no follow function like my research seems to indicate that this is.

So my questions are:

1. What is this related to?
2. Why do i need this?
3. How do i disable this?

Its adding about 2-3 seconds to my page load speed and causing issues with retaining customers so need to resolve this issue.

If you need any further information then I will be happy to provide whatever you need.

Comment: Sounds like functionality provided by this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-followers/ ? If you don’t need this functionality at all, then try and disable the plugin.

Comment: I have not got this plugin in my plugin list. I use the buddyboss one social theme - so i think it is built in?